# how to import a module from level in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
|
|
└── a
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── a.py
└── b
    ├─__init__.py
    └── b.py
```

I want to use method from **a.py in  b.py**

Comment: `import a.a`…? `from a import a`…? `from a.a import *`…?

Comment: from a import * not  working  for me

Comment: 1) Define what "not working for me" means. 2) I didn't suggest `from a import *`.

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't be doing 'import *' if its not totally necessary, which isn't in this case.

Comment: @deceze @Dolfa And yes If he is facing issue in ``` from a import *``` then none of the import will work. He has to define path of module in code or in path.

Comment: @Vaibhav We don't know what the issue he's facing even is! Is it "module 'a' not found"? Then yes, it's a path issue. Or is it that `from a import *` imports everything from `a/__init__.py`, which is unexpected?

Comment: @deceze Actually in comments section he mentioned that ``` from a import *``` doesn't work. So i suggested to add path and check it

Comment: @Vaibhav But he doesn't say what "doesn't work" *means*! It could very well mean the import works just fine, but he's not finding what he expected since he imported the wrong thing.

Comment: @deceze Ya that might be the case. Will see if he comment anything :-)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a method myMethod() in module a.py and you want to import this in b.py then you can first import module a.py in b.py by typing "import a" in b.py header then call the method using import name as a.myMethod() wherever required.